# Convert Associative Array -> Grouping by Value

Tags: php

I have an associative array which looks like this:

[image]

I want to convert it.
It should be grouped by "product_service_category_name" and it should look like this:

```
$productServices = [
'' => [
    1 => 'Diverses Service #1',
    2 => 'Diverses Service #2'
],
'Beratung' => [
    5 => 'Ernährungsberatung'
],
'Massagen' => [
    3 => 'Heilmassage',
    4 => 'Shiatsu'
]
];
```

Please take care about the fact, that the value maybe empty.

Could anybody help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function group($array)
{
    $group = array();
    $key = 'product_service_category_name';
    foreach (array_values($array) as $values) {

        if ( empty($values[$key])) {
            $ptr = 'empty';
        }
        else {
            $ptr = $values[$key];   
        }

        $new_key = $values['product_service_id'];
        $group[$ptr][$new_key] = $values['product_service_name'];   
    }
    return $group;
}

$grouped = group($ungrouped);
```

[Test Here](https://eval.in/672433)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$productServices = [];

foreach ($data as $value) {

    $key = $value['product_service_category_name'];

    if (!isset($productServices[$key])) {
        $productServices[$key] = [];
    }

    $productServices[$key][] = $value['product_service_name'];
}
```

You would need to swap `$data` with whatever the variable is called that is holding the array in your question. The won't work is that array is also called `$productServices`.

Hope this helps!